# Betta fish lying at the bottom of his tank

Tags: fish, betta

I have had my betta fish for around a week and he seems to like to lay on the bottom of his tank. He is in a 5 gallon heated and filtered tank and he occasionally swims around but usually goes right back to the bottom. There are no signs of illness and I bought him from a trusted breeder. He has very long fins, could this be the issue?